# Why is 숙제를 할 수 없어요 weird?

Tags: grammar, meaning

Why is #1 weird while #2 natural?

1. 비록 그 수업을 이해했지만 숙제를 할 수 없어요.
2. 비록 그 수업을 이해했지만 숙제를 하지 못 할것 같아요.

Answer (score 3):

It's because of the difference between -ㄹ 수 없다 and -지 못하다. Korean people usually use -ㄹ 수 없다 and -지 못하다 without distinction...... but anyway there is a subtle difference between them.

'-ㄹ 수 없다' indicates the speaker can't do something because of the situation.
ex) 지금 비가 와서 수영을 할 수 없다 It's raining now and I can't swim

'-지 못하다' is usually used when the speaker can't do something because of lack of your ability.
ex) 나는 첼로를 연주하지 못한다 I can't play the cello

The example above implies that the speaker could not do the homework because of his limitation and lack of ability even though he understood the class. So it sounds natural to use -지 못하다.